# Chrome autocompletes wrong input

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, vue.js, autocomplete

I have a strange issue on Chrome (75.0.3770.142). I have vue app with form and two text inputs with different names. When I try to autocomplete the first one it fills the second one instead (and the first input stays empty). I cannot reproduce it out of my application.

My component

```
    <template>
        <label class="wrapper" :data-error="validation && errors.first(name)" :class="{ error: errors && errors.first(name), label }">
            <span class="label" v-if="label">{{label}}</span>
            <div class="input" :class="{
                'input--search': type === 'search'
            }">
                <input
                    v-if="validation"
                    :aria-label="ariaLabel"
                    v-shortkey.focus="shortKey"
                    :disabled="disabled"
                    :type="type"
                    :class="classes"
                    :value="value"
                    :name="name"
                    :placeholder="placeholder"
                    @search="reset"
                    @input="update"
                    v-validate="validation"
                    :autocomplete="autocomplete"
                />
                <input
                    v-else
                    :aria-label="ariaLabel"
                    v-shortkey.focus="shortKey"
                    :disabled="disabled"
                    :type="type"
                    :class="classes"
                    :value="value"
                    :name="name"
                    :placeholder="placeholder"
                    @search="reset"
                    @input="update"
                    :autocomplete="autocomplete"
                />
                <Icon class="icon" v-if="iconName && !value" :name="iconName" />
            </div>
        </label>
    </template>
```

Form:

```
    <template>
        <form class="form" v-on:submit.prevent>
            <slot />
            <Input
                v-if="isLabel && displayLabel"
                class="label"
                ref="label"
                type="text"
                :label="$t('subscriptions.new.label-placeholder')"
                name="label"
                :validation="{ required: true }"
                :value="label"
                @input="onLabelChange"
            />
            <hr />
            <Terms
                v-if="!termsAccepted"
                :value="terms"
                @input="onTermsToggle"
            />
            <Button
                class="submit button-next"
                submit
                :disabled="nextDisabled"
                @click="next"
            >
                {{ $t('subscriptions.new.next') }}
            </Button>
        </form>
    </template>
```

and screen from Chrome
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCzFA.jpg

video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJtzL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Vue but you can try using input type as tel for telephone field with attributes like name and autocomplete with values as..

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" id="yourid" placeholder="+1-650-123-1234" autocomplete="tel">
```

Not setting autocomplete and incorrect input type for the field could be the reason for this behavior.
Hope this helps.